# Reguar Expression to accept digits + ":" or"." + digits

Tags: c#, regex

I know this might be a novice question regarding Regex in general but I hope someone can help. I need a reg expression that accepts 0-3 digits numbers + zero or 1 occurence of the character ":" or "." + 0-2 digit number. Also there should be no other characters allowed

The user can then input valid numbers like

```
100:,
:0, 
:, 
1, 
10.6, 
111:11
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your definition would match an empty string.  Is that ok?

Comment: What have you tried so far? (The `|` alternation operator is almost certainly what you'll want.)

Comment: If your examples are all valid then I think you have to describe the rules in more detail. The way I read your description only `1,` and `111:11` are valid.

Comment: The ";" in the title does not match the ":" in the question.  Not that it matters much, but you should edit one of them :)

Comment: thanks walrii, its now updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use

```
^\d{0,3}([:\.]\d{0,2})?$
```

The part `\d{0,3}` matches zero to three digits, the part `[:\.]\d{0,2}` matches a `:` or `.`, followed by up to two digits, the braces with the `?` make this part optional. `^` and `$` anchor the expression at the start and end of the string.

See it in action at http://regexr.com?31tqd

Comment: I have tried you answer, however it is turning out to be match for inputs such as 1aa, 1as or any other character after a number. To show you more details- I am using it in a  c# code that goes like   
        
        '{

            Regex regex = new Regex(@"[0-9]{0,3}[:\.]{0,1}[0-9]{0,2}");
            string text = ((TextBox)sender).Text + e.Text;

            
            if(!regex.IsMatch(text))
                e.Handled = true;
   
        }'

Comment: @jepoyscreepers: You need to put the `^` at the beginning and `$` at the end in order to prevent other characters before or after the digits.

Comment: If this answers your question, you can mark this as the accepted answer using the checkmark to the left. =)